# In mongosh, NumberDecimal('1') + NumberDecimal('2') is 12?

Tags: mongodb, concatenation, addition

Why add operator treat as concatentation? How to do addition of two NumberDecimals?

```
//add
> NumberDecimal('1') + NumberDecimal('2')
12

//substract
> NumberDecimal('1') - NumberDecimal('2')
-1

//multipy
> NumberDecimal('1') * NumberDecimal('2')
2

//divide
> NumberDecimal('1') / NumberDecimal('2')
0.5
```

I think there could be another way to do addition of two NumberDecimals.

**I can observe similar behaviors for NumberLong, but not for NumberInt.**

```
NumberInt('1') + NumberInt('2') is 3.
```

Comment: I would guess the `valueOf` method returns a string, as the value is internally stored as a string. The class isn't meant to allow for mathematical operations, it's just to wrap values to indicate to Mongo as what type you want the value to be stored.

Comment: @deceze according documentation is creates a [Decimal128 BSON](https://bsonspec.org/spec.html) object. Math function are not natively implemented on this object.

Comment: Also note that Javascript doesn't safely handle numbers are large enough to require the use of NumberDecimal.  For example: `NumberDecimal("9007199254740991.5") * 3` gives `27021597764222976`

Comment: It's interesting that in `mongosh`, `console.dir(NumberDecimal('1'));` outputs `Decimal128 {bytes: Buffer(16) [Uint8Array] [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 48]}`.